# USING iMACROS to monitor/record HTTP requests (image request) after running Javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, imacros, httpfox

I am working on a project to find a <strike>tool or solution</strike> solution with iMacros that will allow me to automate a large portion of regression testing on our site. The main scenario that I'm trying to make work goes like this:

- Use <strike>tool</strike> **iMacros** to go through a set of actions - in this case,
- a) Visit site
- b) Login to site
- c) Use search bar on screen to search for product
- After the search page loads, there is a header that I need to verify. For this particular scenario, the expected result is "v1=header".

If I were not trying to make a macro from this, I could easily manually find it and observe (i.e. pressing F12 in Chrome, clicking "Network", sorting by the term "b/ss" and finding the "v1=" from the list after the search page loads.

What I cannot seem to do is to record this action, then reply it later and record the results. I am currently evaluating iMacros, by itself and with the Firefox add-on and Chrome extension. iMacros seems to be the answer to this...but all of my searches on how I would make iMacros do exactly this has not been forthcoming.

So far I have tried:

- (Chrome) Pressing F12 in window and in its own window - iMacros would not respond to anything done within that window
- (Firefox) Recording clicks and button presses while using HTTPFox when viewing the results - again, iMacros would not respond to anything in that window
- Having iMacros take a screenshot while HTTPFox was open with the information I was looking for - the screenshot only showed the page without the HTTPFox information.

Considering I have very little experience with html and javascript, I'm running out of options to search for. Anything that anyone can come up with would be *greatly* appreciated. Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: Try [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) maybe. Tool requests are not suitable for the SO Q&A format, which is why you're downvoted.

Comment: Well, I guess I could just change it to be asking for iMacros help - but I feel like leaving out a tool request would be shooting myself in the foot if there is a better solution...which is what I'm aiming for.

This is why I rarely actively post questions.

Comment: +1 better title. Usually if you ask to do something, and there's a well-known tool for it, somebody will mention the tool. I think iMacros actually might work for you. Is v1=header part of the [query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string)?

Comment: It is. When a search is performed on the page while Chrome's devtools is open, on the"Network" tab at the top and filtered for "b/ss", there is one entry that shows (very long, could not copy/paste). Clicking this entry and scrolling down through "Headers" you find the "Query String Parameters" section - it is within this section that you find the "v1" section. For this scenario, I'm looking to run a macro that performs this search AND records the "v1" response to a file. 

I've been staring at iMacros help for days, and I think my brain is starting to leak out of my ears...

Comment: [Here's a screenshot, if it helps](http://tinypic.com/r/4lri3l/8)

Comment: Since the query string parameters are part of the URL, you might be able to get the whole URL using [`!URLCURRENT`](http://wiki.imacros.net/!URLCURRENT), then extract the v1 section from it. You need to look into [scripting](http://wiki.imacros.net/Web_Scripting), recording is not enough. And if iMacros cannot do everything you want, look for [alternative tools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_web_testing_tools). Good luck.

Comment: I noticed while doing some simple tests with using "!URLCURRENT" with an extraction command and using SAVEAS to save it to a file that the URL it saved does not display the "V1=" string itself.

Speaking with a colleague earlier, they explained that it is a tracking pixel "built dynamically in javascript functions itself and will never be seen in the source" - which means iMacros would have to be set to somehow monitor the HTTP requests as the page loads and explicit calls to javascript files. 

At any rate, thank you very much for your time and patience. :)

Answer (score 1):

Determined that iMacros does not have the capability to do what is needed, and will not recognize any web dev panel (firebug, httpfox, etc) when recording macros or screenshots.

Utilized approxiblue's suggesting to check out Selenium (Webdriver), which after a week of code-surgeoning with examples from various sites, was able to piece together a combo of Webdriver/Firefox/Firebug/NetExport to listen to the http requests when performing a search and then exporting the events to a .HAR file.